# Mongo and Node.js: Finding a document by _id using a UUID (GUID)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mean-stack

I'm developing a restAPI using node.js and i'm trying to query a mongo collection. I can query using strings (for example "companyname") but I need to be able to query the "_id" element in the document.

In mongo the _id is currently stored like this (as a GUID):

```
{
"_id" : new BinData(3, "MH+t3q6PD0SxVR5z7/pzfw=="), 
"companyname" : "TestCompany",
"databasename" : "TestDataBase",
}
```

This is what my current GET method looks like:

```
exports.getBusinessCardData = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    //"id" = MH+t3q6PD0SxVR5z7/pzfw==

    tradeShowAdminDB.collection('clients', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id': id}, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};
```

The "id" coming into the method is Base64 string format ("MH+t3q6PD0SxVR5z7/pzfw==") and using that  the query returns nothing (i'm assuming as it's not the correct type/format). My question is how do I get that "id" into the correct format so that I can query mongo using the _id?

I've been looking for ages and can't seem to find a solution and the documentation seems very vague on anything that isn't a 24 character hex ObjectId. Any help would be very much appreciated! 


Additional information:

I'm using node v0.10.33 and express v4.x

The mongo driver I am using is just the base javascript mongo driver for node. 
(found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)

Comment: maybe `findOne({'_id': new BinData(3, id)}`??

Comment: I've tried that but BinData needs to be a type and there is no definition for it in the mongo library

Comment: Where does `BinData` even come from? It is not a Node global. Could you show the imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i've found the solution to get the base64 string into a GUID format within node, to convert it this needs to be done:

```
var mongo.require('mongodb');
var GUID = new mongo.Binary(new Buffer(<base65String>, 'base64'), 3);
```

and now i can query the database like this:

```
collection.findOne({'_id' : GUID}, function(err, item) {
                    res.send(item);
                });
```

Comment: What would be useful here is to add code to convert guid/uuid into base64, It's not as straightforward as one would hope. I ended up using "npm install --save slugid" and then append '==' to it and convert underscores to slashes. That leaves a bit of a bad aftertaste though.

Comment: I've been searching for two days for this solution.  Records are being created by a C# application in this old type 3 format that I don't control.  This worked like a charm with no modification.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert the id in your GET method to a BinData() object just like it is shown in your sample document.

In your current code it searches for _id matching a string (MH+t3q6PD0SxVR5z7/pzfw== in your sample).

Comment: How would i get it into a BinData Object? i can't seem to find any reference on it at all, It works fine in mongo shell as it has a type definition for BinData but the library for node js doesn't

Comment: How was the data inserted into the collection? It is a bit strange for the driver to choose to use a BinData instance in the first place

Comment: It's inserted in there using C# with the mongo driver

Comment: :-/ your problem is that the datatype you use in your query doesn't match the type used to store the data. You either need to figure out how to convince the node driver to create a BinData object or change the C# code so it will insert the data as a string

Comment: Sadly i don't have the option of being able to change the format of the ids, maybe i'll have to develop something that will convert it to a BinData object, i'm just surprised no one else has tried to do the same thing

Comment: BinData() is a BSON data type so the best bet will be to have a look at the JS BSON implementation used by the driver https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson

Comment: Brilliant! I'll have a look into that, i'll let you know how i get on! Cheers!