# mongoose: Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I try to add a location to a company model I get this **Unable to invalidate a subdocument that has not been added to an array.**

My schema looks like this:

```
var companySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    locations: [{
        address: String,
        loc: {
            type: [Number],
            index: '2d'
        }
    }],
});
```

The update which performs the addition of a location

```
// I am very unsure if I can creata a location this way
var newLocation = 
{
    address: address,
    loc:
    {
        type: [long, lat]
    }
};

CompanyModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    company_id, 
    { $push: { locations: newLocation } }, 
    {new: true},
    function(err, updatedCompany) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if(!updatedCompany)
        {
            res.sendError({
                error: 'INVALID_COMPANY_ID'
            });
        }
        else
        {
            res.sendSuccess({
                data:
                {
                    company: updatedCompany
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Do you know why I am receiving this error? I do not receive a stack trace.

Comment: As a sidebar to your actual problem here, I would advise you to move away from the idea of storing geolocation data within a subdocument array here. The problem is that while MongoDB can "find" the nearest document with geospatial data in an array, it cannot "exclude" items in the array that are "not near" the queried location ( or `$geoWithin` by itself for that matter ). The example is the array stores both "New York" and "Tokyo" location data. A query is made for "New Jersey" and this is "near" to "New York", but nowhere neat "Tokyo". But the full document is retutned. No way around that.

Comment: Onto your question. Your var is wrong. Should be `{ address: address, loc:[long, lat] };` As "type" is the definition of the mongoose schema, and not the structure of the document itself.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for answering.
If you've got the time, would you explain more in detail on why it is bad?
I understand it like this:
A company has 2 offices. One in new york and one in tokyo. When I want to get all companies near a user that lives in new york, I can't exclude tokyos office from the result?

Comment: The best you can do is match "New York" only. If "Long Island" were there then that would be ignonored. The technique needs [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) of the aggregation pipeline, and specifically other aggregation techniques. But this is a different question to what you asked. **This** question is answered by my previous comment. You declared the object you wanted to `$push` incorrectly in a way that does not match the schema. This is your error. And not really a reference help point, hence not an answer.

Comment: Doodlemeat, would you add an answer below that summarises Blakes Seven's solution? I don't know if it might be helpful for future readers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo and Node.js: Finding a document by \_id using a UUID (GUID)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018257/mongo-and-node-js-finding-a-document-by-id-using-a-uuid-guid)